# Have background service running on React

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am working on a file upload system using `react-dropzone`. I can successfully upload a file and display the file name and size underneath the drag/drop div.

[image: Current App Condition]

I have been trying, with great failure, **to get the drag/drop area to run in the background once there are files being displayed**. But I cannot do this. I know it can be done as this is how Dropbox, Google Drive and pretty much every other file uploading site works. What is the best way to achieve this?

Here is my work is done so far;

**FileUploader container**

```
onFileUploader = ( files ) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        this.setState({...this.state, files : this.state.files.concat(file)})

        const jsonFile = new FormData();
        jsonFile.append('file', file)
        jsonFile.append('multichainAddress', this.state.multichainAddress);

        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: jsonFile,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("post success - ", response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("post failed - ", error);
            });
    });

    this.setState({...this.state, filesUploaded : true});
    console.log(this.state.files);
}

render () {
    console.log("[FileUploader] render");

    return (
        <Aux>
            <div>
                <Grid container spacing={8}>
                    <Grid item md={10}>
                        <FileDropzone onDropHandler={this.onFileUploader} dropzoneReference={this.onDropzoneRef}/>
                        <Files files={this.state.files} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={2} >
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            component="span"
                            onClick={() => {
                                this.dropzoneRef.open();
                            }}
                        >
                            Upload
                            <CloudUploadIcon />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

**FileDropzone component**

```
render () {
    return (
        <section>
            <div>
                <Dropzone
                    onDrop={this.props.onDropHandler}
                    className={classes.FileDropzone}
                    ref={(node) => {
                        this.props.dropzoneReference(node);
                    }}
                >
                    Drag n drop files here
                </Dropzone>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

So far, I have tried hiding the element, but that seems to disable it too. I have also tried adding the prop `preventDropOnDocument` to the `Dropzone` component but that did nothing.

Comment: well what have you tried so far?? what does the `onDropHandler` do?

Comment: I have just updated my question with your answers